# are there any risk to get garbage value when casting unsigned long to int?

Tags: c

I want to assign the `ARRAY_SIZE(X)` to an `int`. are there any risk to get garbage value in the `int` since `ARRAY_SIZE(X)` is an `unsigned long`

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) (sizeof((X))/sizeof((X)[0]))
int m = ARRAY_SIZE(X)
```

are there a risk to get garbage value in `m`?

Comment: Only if the value is greater than `INT_MAX`. Integer casts are well-defined.

Comment: `ARRAY_SIZE(X)` is `size_t`, which you really should be using as the type of `m`.

Comment: Why are you asking if there is *any* risk when you already have an example where garbage is produced?

Comment: @ScottHunter, In fact I want to be sure that the cause is casting issue. and to understand why

Comment: To be pedantic you could check `if ( ARRAY_SIZE(X) > INT_MAX ) { ...error handling...}` before proceeding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't get garbage  (as in completely unpredictable) values.

Narrowing conversions to signed types when the value won't fit in the target type will either be implementation-defined or they'll raise a signal ([6.3.1.3p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3)).

If they don't raise a signal, you can verify absence  of information loss by checking the values and signs of the source and destination are the same.

(If you store into *unsigned*s, the conversion will always be well defined, and you'll only need to compare the values (no signs in unsigned types) to verify absence of information loss.)

Answer (score -1):

If the value in `ARRAY_SIZE(x)` is bigger than what can fit in an `int`, you can't help but get garbage.

Comment: I get garbage value when array size is 0

Comment: If an element is part of an array, and the array size is 0, what would you expect the element size to be?

Comment: @MOHAMED - An array size of 0 is not allowed. Your compiler should complain